# Determine how similar groups of data are to each other

Tags: probability, distributions, subset

I have a pool of 15,000 unique* items. From that set, there are roughly 3200 sets of 60 items, selected non-randomly (in fact, for the sake of the framing of the question, let's say that each item is intentionally chosen for a specific reason). I have the list of all items that are in at least one set; said list is about 5500 items long, and also includes the total number of sets each item is in. The most popular item is in roughly 60% of the sets, and the list goes all the way down to items that only appear in 1 set.

Additionally, there are similarities that exist between the different sets that manifest themselves in the form of tendencies. For instance (with random values given), 30% of the sets are similar according to one "tendency group", and tend to include items #1, #50, #2006, etc. more often than other tendency groups; 20% might be similar to each other in a different way, and tend to include items #65, #700, #5000, etc. more often than other tendency groups. Thus, there's not exactly one set of "expected values" (which would make this question similar to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403242/how-to-calculate-if-two-samples-data-are-similar)), but rather upwards of a dozen groups of "somewhat similar values." I looked also at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92085/given-two-sets-how-can-i-say-statistically-if-they-are-similar-different), but, as someone with a limited grasp of the subject, it doesn't seem like it's exactly what I'm looking for.

**How do I compare each set to each other in such a way that I'm able to compare each item from a given set and see how it compares to other items that appear in similar sets?**

Specifically, if given a specific set, if I were to replace one item, which item would I take out, and what would I replace it with, to make the set more similar (less unique) compared to other sets. Extra points if the method is capable of making the set more similar to one specific (or perhaps simply being selective towards one) tendency group (or more).

In typing out this question, I've become aware of the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), but that seems like it's more suited for comparing two sets of data to each other, not looking at an individual item across multiple sets and looking for similarities in that respect, but I could very much be wrong.

*I say unique; even though they may differ in one aspect, some items functionally or even have exactly the same characteristics except for their name, but I'm not sure how much that matters.

Edit1: the unique items are *[Magic: the Gathering](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=commander%3AWUBG%20legal%3Acommander)* cards, and the sets represent individual decks. Does that help?

Edit2: Since posting this question, I have become aware of the existence of "market basket" analysis, but, as a laymen in this field, I have no idea where to even begin to conduct said analysis.

Comment: Perhaps the approach needs to be to compute a Jaccard index for each set when compared to each other set, then go from there?

Comment: This would be a lot clearer if you told us what these items are and what the sets are.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica Is that enough detail?

Comment: The block where you say of "similar sets" is obscure to me. How is this similarity represented? some matrix? what constitute it dimensions and values?

Comment: or is it the similarity that you know not but want to investigate, i.e. like "due to which items, common in both, these two given sets are similar?".

Comment: The second one; I know that the decks have similarity, but I don't know how to measure said similarity. As a starting point, if fifty decks have items 1, 75, 206, and 2009, and fifty decks have items 2, 25, 306, and 150000, if I have a third deck, what is a quantitative way of determining if a third deck is closer in construction to either of the first two decks?

Comment: ...with the subsequent step being if I want deck three to be closer to one of the particular decks, which item should I remove and/or which item should I add that will make deck 3 more like one of the other two?

Comment: There are many-many ways to _define_ what makes two sets similar. The simplest way is indeed Jaccard-idea similarity. It is the number of items shared by the two sets divided by the combined number of items possessed by the sets. Logically, if you add to setA _any_ item possesed already by setB you make the sets closer; or you remove from setA _any_ item not possessed by setB you again make them closer. What makes you dissatisfied with this? You probably have some additional "constraints" or "goals" in mind, what are they then?

Comment: @ttnphns The Magic: the Gathering format I have in mind is very casual, so sometimes decks aren't exactly built to be the most competitive. If I have a set of decks that include item #1, I want to take a look at all other decks that include #1 and statistically analyze what other items those decks tend to include. So for instance: 50% of decks w/ #1 also have #5; 42% w/ #1 have #1000; etc. So the percentage of cards that are *the same* may be...40%? 30%?

Comment: @ttnphns If I have a set of 60 items, I want to be able to select one of them and know if and by how much that item is making that set more like the "average" set. If possible, I'd like to also take this a step further: given that decks that include item #1 may not all be the same "archetype", and if decks that include #1 can be categorized according to, say, 5 archetypes, then the stretch goal, if you will, is to be able to "guess" which archetype a given set is leaning towards, then select a given item and see if and by how much that item is leaning me towards or away from said archetype.

Comment: Maybe consider analysing the contingency table `items x sets`. Entries in the table being the frequencies or some secondarily computed affinity values between rows and columns. Do simple [correspondence analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis) or do _multidimensional unfolding_, to visually map item-set affininies as well as similarity between sets due to most prominent co-affinities. Another approach could be _biclustering_ which clusters rows and columns of the data table simultaneously.

Comment: Look also for so called TURF analysis, which might help.

Comment: @ttnphns How would I determine "most prominent co-affinities"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear from your question exactly what your objective is for this analysis, but if I understand correctly, you would like to be able to quantify the similarity (or "distance") between two MtG decks, so that you can alter a deck to make it more or less similar to other decks in the sample.  As I will show below, this exercise is essentially equivalent to asking how we can measure "similarity" or "distance" between categorical random variables falling over some fixed set of categories.

---

Suppose you have $n$ cards and $m$ decks and let $r_{i,j}$ represent the count of card $i$ in deck $j$.$^\dagger$  You can hold all of these count values in an $n \times m$ matrix which is the [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) for the data:

$$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix} 
r_{1,1} & r_{1,2} & \cdots & r_{1,m} \\ 
r_{2,1} & r_{2,2} & \cdots & r_{2,m} \\ 
\vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\ 
r_{n,1} & r_{n,2} & \cdots & r_{n,m} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Each column $\mathbf{r}_{j}$ represents a single deck, giving the count values for each card in the deck (most of which will be zeros).  One useful way to think of a deck is as a categorical *random variable* giving a random card from that deck.  Let $X_j$ be a random card from deck $j$, which has distribution:

$$X_j \sim \text{Categorical}(\boldsymbol{p}_j)
\quad \quad \quad \boldsymbol{p}_j = \frac{\mathbf{r}_j}{r_{\bullet j}}.$$

Since each deck is represented by a categorical random variable, we can employ statistical measures of association between categorical random variables.  For example, the chi-squared measure of association between decks $j$ and $j'$ is obtained by looking at the $n \times 2$ contingency table for only those two decks:

$$\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \Bigg[ \frac{(r_{\bullet \bullet} r_{i,j} - r_{i \bullet} r_{\bullet j})^2}{r_{\bullet \bullet} r_{i \bullet}r_{\bullet j}} + \frac{(r_{\bullet \bullet} r_{i,j'} - r_{i \bullet} r_{\bullet j'})^2}{r_{\bullet \bullet} r_{i \bullet} r_{\bullet j'}} \Bigg].$$

This is a standard measure of association for categorical random variables, so it will be easy for others to recognise, and its properties are well-known.  It can be extended to get a more general measure of the similarity between a set of decks, by enlarging the contingency table to include the relevant set of decks.  In order to alter a deck to make it more similar to another individual deck, or set of decks, you would remove a card that is not present in any/many of those decks, and replace it with a card that brings its count of that card more into line with those other decks.  This could be done mathematically, by looking at the change in the chi-squared statistic for each possible change of cards (perhaps narrowing it down to sensible choices first, to make this computationally feasible).

The subject of measuring association between categorical variables is a large field, and I cannot give a full exposition here.  The above chi-squared statistic is one example of a measure of association for categorical variables.  More broadly, I would recommend that you compile your data into a contingency table of the above form, and select an appropriate measure of association for categorical variables, based on consideration of the available statistics in the statistical literature.

---

$^\dagger$ To simplify the problem, you might consider ignoring the basic land cards, in which case $n$ represents the number of cards that are not basic lands.  These remaining cards have a deck limit of four under the rules, which limits the counts to the possible values $r_{i,j} = 0,1,...,4$.

Comment: Excellent! Now let me see if I can noodle through this...one thing that might make this easier OR harder is that it's EDH/Commander decks, so other than basic lands, you can only include one of any specific card in the deck.

Comment: That shouldn't make it fundamentally more difficult.  I would recommend removing consideration of basic lands though; otherwise one of the main drivers of correlation will just be the number of lands of each type in each deck.

Comment: I apologize: I recognize the Sigma notation, but what do the bullets mean?

Comment: No problem --- in this context, bullets just denote summation over that index, so $r_{i \bullet} \equiv \sum_j r_{i,j}$ and $r_{\bullet j} \equiv \sum_i r_{i,j}$.

Comment: Also, what does "rr_i,j" mean? What's with the extra r?

Comment: @"Reinstate Monica" (don't know if that'll work): I think I figured out the last question: deck inclusion percentages will allow me to calculate "expected values". But I'm still puzzled over the double r.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit ambiguous --- $r = r_{\bullet \bullet} = \sum_i \sum_j r_{i,j}$.  I have edited to use the double-bullet notation instead, to make it clearer.

Comment: So essentially, since it's Commander, the summation of ri is always going to be 1 and the summation of rj is always going to be the number of decks that that card appears in total, right?

Comment: The $r$ values are the counts, but you are summing them over decks/cards.  They will not always sum to one.

Comment: Okay, I have more questions, but this isn't exactly the best method for this. Are you available elsewhere?

Comment: Did you get my last comment?

Comment: @John Doe: If your questions can be framed clearly as another SE.CV post that would be of broad interest, that is probably the best way to do it.  (I cannot guarantee posting an answer, but if you link to your new question, I'll take a look.)  I am available outside this forum, but only for teaching assistance for students at my own university (ANU), or as a paid statistical consultant for others (which is expensive).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calculating the cophenetic distance(also called cophenetic coefficient).
For items belonging to multiple sets, we can evaluate the average cophenetic distance of the object from the other set.

Here is a link to the brief description of the same:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cophenetic

It can be evaluated from this function in python:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cophenet.html

Comment: In order to calculate a cophenetic correlation/similarity/distance one must have first 1) the distance matrix between the "objects", 2) do cluster analysis of the objects or borrow some their grouping results from somewhere. It is so far unclear how this answers the OP question. Maybe you will want to expand your answer to make it clearer?